# Como pegar a variação com relação ao número de dias da diferença de datas no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho uma tabela em csv com 5 informações, duas com datas, duas com preços, e uma com a diferença entre as datas.

- Tenho a data 1 fixada em uma data e a data 2 variando.

Por exemplo:

10/01/2018 > 11/01/2018
10/01/2018 > 12/01/2018
...

- Tenho o percentual da variação que peguei através do script abaixo:

`Tipo1_X <- (sd(Tipo1$precoin, na.rm = T)/mean(Tipo1$precoin, na.rm = T))*100
Tipo2_X <- (sd(Tipo2$precoin, na.rm = T)/mean(Tipo2$precoin, na.rm = T))*100
Tipo3_X <- (sd(Tipo3$precoin, na.rm = T)/mean(Tipo3$precoin, na.rm = T))*100
Tipo1_XX <- (sd(Tipo1$precoout, na.rm = T)/mean(Tipo1$precoout, na.rm = T))*100
Tipo2_XX <- (sd(Tipo2$precoout, na.rm = T)/mean(Tipo2$precoout, na.rm = T))*100
Tipo3_XX <- (sd(Tipo3$precoout, na.rm = T)/mean(Tipo3$precoout, na.rm = T))*100`

- Agora, preciso saber a variação de dias com relação a esse preço. Por exemplo:

Tenho do dia 10/01/2018 ao dia 11/01/2018, depois do dia 10/01/2018 ao dia 12/01/2018.. Do dia 10 ao dia 11 é 1 dia de diferença, do dia 10 ao dia 12 são 2 dias. Preciso pegar, a variação com relação ao número de dias da diferença, mas não estou conseguindo achar um rumo pra fazer isso em R. :(

PS: Exemplificando como seria o resultado:

Em diferenças de datas de 2 dias o preço varia em 10%,
em diferenças de datas de 30 dias o preço varia 5% e assim por diante.

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta com a saída de `dput(Tipo1)` ou se a tabela for muito grande com a saída de `dput(head(Tipo1, 20))`, por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tenho a certeza que a pergunta esteja muito clara e se calhar convinha colocar um pouco de informação adicional. De qualquer das formas, assumindo que queres sempre calcular a diferença face a 10-01-2018, então o que precisas é de utilizar índices. Podes calcular os resultados que procuras da seguinte forma:

```
Diff_2_dias <- (valor_12012018/valor_100120118 -1) * 100
Diff_30_dias <- (valor_09022018/valor_100120118 -1) * 100
```

**Nota**: as variáveis são exemplificativas, tens de escolher os valores que estejam de acordo com a tua dataframe e podes usar o R base sem precisar de qualquer package.

Uma vez que estás a manipular sérias temporais, aconselho-te a dar uma vista de olhos à documentação do package XTS e converteres a série numa série temporal. Vai-te poupar muito tempo na manipulação de dados.

https://rpubs.com/mohammadshadan/288218

https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/r-xts-cheat-sheet